# How do I test that a Vue component responds to an event emitted by $root?

Tags: unit-testing, events, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have a component that listens for an event emitted by the Vue $root instance.

```
export default {
   data() {
     return {
       name: ''
     }

   },
   methods: {
     openModal(name) {
       this.name = name
     }
   },
   mounted() {
     this.$root.$on('open-modal', name => {
       this.openModal(name);
     });
   }
 }
```

And I have another place the code where I'm calling that event.

```
this.$root.$emit('open-modal', 'some-name');
```

How can I write a unit test that calls that event on $root and asserts the event has been called? I'm using Vue test utils https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/ and can't find a way to call the event.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
it('sets the modal name on the open-modal event', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Modal);
    wrapper.vm.$root.$emit('open-modal', 'my-modal')
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.name).to.equal('my-modal');
  });
```

Comment: This may be relevant: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/6

Comment: Thanks @RoyJ I'm not really as interested in listening for the event as I am in emitting it though.

Comment: I think your emit is correct. The reason you're not seeing the data update is that there has not been idle time for the handler to respond before you test it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. I was emitting the event correctly. The problem was my component is using VueRouter and calling $router.push() in the openModal method (I left that out of the code example to keep it short). I had to stub VueRouter in my test and everything worked fine. Here's what my test looks like now.

```
import { shallow, createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Modal from '../cw-modal.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);


describe('cw-modal component', () => {
  it('sets visible to true when the "open-modal" even is called with the modalName', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Modal, {
      propsData: {
        cwModalName: 'my-modal'
      },
      localVue,
      router: new VueRouter()
    });

    wrapper.vm.$root.$emit('open-modal', 'my-modal');
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.visible).to.equal(true);
  });
}
```